# Is a stack overflow a security hole?

Tags: security, stack-overflow, code-injection

Note:  this question relates to stack overflows (think infinite recursion), NOT buffer overflows.

If I write a program that is correct, but it accepts an input from the Internet that determines the level of recursion in a recursive function that it calls, is that potentially sufficient to allow someone to compromise the machine?

I know someone might be able to crash the process by causing a stack overflow, but could they inject code?  Or does the c runtime detect the stack overflow condition and abort cleanly?

Just curious...

Comment: "accepts (an) input from the Internet ... is that potentially sufficient to allow someone to compromise the machine?" Derp herp.

Comment: Surely even if it aborts cleanly you still have a problem?  A process that's continuously restarting isn't going to be servicing many user requests.

Comment: Anyway it should be at meta at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, since it is about stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Rapid Refresher

First off, you need to understand that the fundamental units of protection in modern OSes are the process and the memory page. Processes are memory protection domains; they are the level at which an OS enforces security policy, and they thus correspond strongly with a running program. (Where they don't, it's either because the program is running in multiple processes or because the program is being shared in some kind of framework; the latter case has the potential to be “security-interesting” but that's 'nother story.) Virtual memory pages are the level at which the hardware applies security rules; every page in a process's memory has attributes that determine what the process can do with the page: whether it can read the page, whether it can write to it, and whether it can execute program code on it (though the third attribute is rather more rarely used than perhaps it should be). Compiled program code is mapped into memory into pages that are both readable and executable, but not writable, whereas the stack should be readable and writable, but not executable. *Most memory pages are not readable, writable or executable at all;* the OS only lets a process use as many pages as it explicitly asks for, and that's what memory allocation libraries (`malloc()` et al.) manage for you.

### Analysis

Provided each stack frame is smaller than a memory page<sup>[1]</sup> so that, as the program advances through the stack, it writes to each page, the OS (i.e., the privileged part of the runtime) can at least in principle detect stack overflows reliably and terminate the program if that occurs. Basically, all that happens to do this detection is that there is a page that the program cannot write to at the end of the stack; if the program tries to write to it, the memory management hardware traps it and the OS gets a chance to intervene.

The potential problems with this come if the OS can be tricked into not setting such a page or if the stack frames can become so large and sparsely written to that the guard page is jumped over. (Keeping more guard pages would help prevent the second case with little cost; forcing variable-sized stack allocations – e.g., `alloca()` – to always write to the space they allocate before returning control to the program, and so detect a smashed stack, would prevent the first with some cost in terms of speed, though the writes could be reasonably sparse to keep the cost fairly small.)

### Consequences

What are the consequences of this? Well, the OS has to do the right thing with memory management. (@Michael's link illustrates what can happen when it gets that wrong.) But also it is dangerous to let an attacker determine memory allocation sizes where you don't force a write to the whole allocation immediately; `alloca` and C99 variable-sized arrays are a particular threat. Moreover, I would be more suspicious of C++ code as that tends to do a lot more stack-based memory allocation; it might be OK, but there's a greater potential for things to go wrong.

Personally, I prefer to keep stack sizes and stack-frame sizes small anyway and do all variable-sized allocations on the heap. In part, this is a legacy of working on some types of embedded system and with code which uses very large numbers of threads, but it does make protecting against stack overflow attacks much simpler; the OS can reliably trap them and all the attacker has then is a denial-of-service (annoying, but rarely fatal). I don't know whether this is a solution for all programmers.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Typical page sizes: 4kB on 32-bit systems, 16kB on 64-bit systems. Check your system documentation for what it is in your environment.

Answer (score 3):

Most systems (like Windows) exit when the stack is overflowed.  I don't think you are likely to see a security issue here.  At least, not an elevation of privilege security issue.  You could get some denial of service issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universally correct answer... on some system the stack might grow down or up to overwrite other memory that the program's using (or another program, or the OS), but on any well designed, vaguely security-conscious OS (Linux, any common UNIX variant, even Windows) there will be no rights escalation potential.  On some systems, with stack size checks disabled, the address space might approach or exceed the free virtual memory size, allowing memory exhaustion to negatively affect or even bring down the entire machine rather than just the process, but on good OSes by default there's a limit on that (e.g. Linux's limit / ulimit commands).

Worth mentioning that it's typically pretty easy to use a counter to put an arbitrary but generous limit of recursive depth too: you can use a static local variable if single-threaded, or a final parameter (conveniently defaulted to 0 if your language allows it, else have an outer caller provide 0 the first time).

Comment: +1 for limiting the possible recursive depth.  Any internet input should be viewed as a suggestion, not as a command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. There are algorithms to avoid recursiveness. For example in case arithmetic expressions the [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) enable you to avoid recursiveness. The main idea behind is to alter the original expression. There could be some algorythm that can help you as well.

One other problem with stack overflow, that if error handling is not appropiate, it can cause anything. To explain it for example in Java [StackOverflowError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) is an error, and it is caught if someone catches [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), which is a common mistake. So error handling is a key question in case of stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Availability is an important aspect of security, that is mostly overlooked.

Don't fall into that pit.

## edit

As an example of poorly understood security-consciousness in modern OSs, take a look at a relatively newly discovered [vulnerability](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2010/08/skeletons-hidden-in-linux-closet.html) that nobody yet patched completely. There are countless other examples of privilege escalation vulnerabilities that OS developers have written off as denial of service attacks.

Comment: The question goes out of its way to state that that distinction is already understood.  It's possible that, for instance, the process handling the client connection is forked off and can fail independently of other services, so it's possible to design a system that maintains availability through crash-tolerance rather than safeguarding each process.

Comment: My answer stands for itself. Still, I added an example that might be informative.

Comment: If the program doesn't do large `alloca` calls or other large stack allocations (where “large” means in excess of a memory page) *and* the OS keeps an always-unallocated page between the stack and the heap, then that vulnerability is very tough to exploit (i.e., requires some other way to smash the stack pointer too) since the non-page acts as a partition between stack and heap. Otherwise, the fix would require real segmentation of stack and heap pointers, and that would suck. (It sucked donkey balls back on the 8086 in the '80s; let's not go there again!)